# Read .properties file every minute

Tags: java, servlets, properties

I do a small task. My task is read message from .properties file in `servlet` and then pass it to `jsp`. I did it.
Now I need to read `.properties` file every minute.
I have no idea how to do it.
Can anybody help me?

This is my classes:
MessageController

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MessageController extends HttpServlet {
    private Messenger messenger;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        messenger = new Messenger();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("message", messenger.getMessage("POST", request.getParameter("username"), getServletContext()));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        getServletContext().getAttribute("abc");
        request.setAttribute("message", messenger.getMessage("GET", request.getParameter("username"), getServletContext()));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Messeger (read properties file and form message):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Messenger{
    private static final String MESSAGE_PATH = "/WEB-INF/properties/message.properties";

    public String getMessage(String requestType, String username, javax.servlet.ServletContext context) {
        Properties properties = readPropertiesFile(context);
        String message = formMessage(username, requestType, properties);
        return message;
    }

    private Properties readPropertiesFile(javax.servlet.ServletContext context){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(context.getResourceAsStream(MESSAGE_PATH));
        } catch (IOException exception) {
        }
        return properties;
    }

    private String formMessage(String username, String requestType, Properties properties){
        if(requestType == null) requestType = "Unknown";
        if(username == null || username.isEmpty()) username = "Unnamed";
        String message = MessageFormat.format(properties.getProperty("text"), username, requestType);
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `timer` or `scheduler` to trigger your read method.

Comment: If it's in a `Servlet`, you could set up some kind of value which stores the last time the file was read and when the last read time is more than a minute ago, re-read the file.  Otherwise, you could just re-read the file on each request...

Comment: @MadProgrammer a good simple approach.  No point fetching the file if no servlet activity.

Comment: why you want to read every min? you might need to read only when properties files changes. For that you might use java.nio package. java.nio.file.WatchService.java might be useful.

Comment: @Mahendra it's my task : re-read file every minute

Comment: logically doesn't make sense to re-read same file again and again. Still make use of multi-threading and schedule thread to run every minute.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think this would be a best approach. In a servlet it is a bad idea to start new threads if unnecessary.

Comment: You have to remember, a `Servlet` is a request/response pattern.  The `Servlet` shouldn't be doing anything beyond the scope.  A `Timer` isn't going to help here (IMHO) as might have multiple instance of the same `Servlet` running...you need to store some kind stateful, local value (`System.currentTimeMillis()`) which you can retrieve and compare to the current time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your use case is to return the most up-to-date values from the property file, you might consider using Apache Commons Configuration and its FileChangedReloadingStrategy.

Using the FileChangedReloadingStrategy the property file is checked for modifications as soon as you access the configuation (based on the modification date of the properties file). If a change has been detected the property file is loaded into the configuration.

see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_filebased.html

This will ensure that the properties always reflect the values given in the file. No need to define timers or use scheduling frameworks.

Comment: Thank!
But i still don't understand how to reload JSP when file is changed

Comment: You can't reload the JSP when the file is changed. Loading a JSP is triggered by a client (e.g. browser) while the file is changed on the server. If you would like to update a webpage as soon as a property has been changed, you could either use websockets or use ajax to poll the server in the background.

Using websockets is a rather sophisticated approach as it requires modern browsers and web containers. Ajax may be easier for you as you will find more examples on the internet.

While websockets allow for immediate update where the server informs the client, ajax depends on polling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ServletContextListener and Timer for this purpose.
Just create Listener:

```
public class PropertiesListener implements ServletContextListener {

        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            Timer time = new Timer();
            TimerTask readPropertiesTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //read from properties
                }
            };
            time.schedule(readPropertiesTask, 0, 60000); 
        }

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}
}
```

and register it in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>PropertiesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: How then pass this data to the controller?

Comment: You can try to save your data to ServletContext and then in controller take this data.

Comment: And then my page will be updated when some request goes to the controller?

Comment: Can i call controller, for example, if properties is changed?

Answer (score 0):

If your using spring you can use a simple trigger bean which can call a method that deals with reading the porperties file. As an idea you can use the [org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html) in your java if you choose to, to manage loading the properties file for you.

```
<!-- Class that handles file reading -->
<bean id="propertyFileReader" class="org.myCompany.PropertyFileReader">
</bean>

<!-- Quartz job beans -->
<bean id="propertyFileReaderJobDetail"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="propertyFileReader" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="runLoadPropertiesFile" /> <!-- Method in your class you want to run -->
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>
<bean id="propertyFileReaderJobDetailSimpleTrigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="propertyFileReaderJobDetail" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="60000" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="60000" /><!-- every minute -->
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="propertyFileReaderJobDetailSimpleTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now your java code

```
public class PropertyFileReader
{
    private PropertiesConfiguration configuration;

    public PropertyFileReader() 
    {
        configuration = new PropertiesConfiguration("my property file location");
        configuration.addConfigurationListener(new ConfigurationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void configurationChanged(ConfigurationEvent event)
            {
                 // Do what needs to be done here
            }
        });
    }

    /**
    * Method called by quartz timer for reloading properties file
    */
    public void runLoadPropertiesFileg()
    {
        // Check if properties have changed.
        // In this example I am using apache PropertiesConfiguration.
        // Performs a reload operation if necessary. Events will be passed to 
        //configuration listeners.
        configuration.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, but i don't use Spring

Comment: Ah never mind. In that case you can use igor-meli's trigger and the apache PropertiesConfiguration if its helpful :-) have a good day!